# TeamCity notify the cuprit from upstream build

Tags: teamcity

We have 2 project configurations **A** and **B**. **B** depends on **A**. A commiter makes a change in project **A** that causes build failure in downstream project **B**.

Is there a way in TeamCity to notify the commiter of project A that the B has failed because of his change?

Jenkins/Hudson supports that using `upstream-individuals:A` as an email address in this particular situation.

Comment: What type of dependency is there between A and B? Is it a snapshot or artifact dependency?

Comment: I do not have a dependency configured between those 2 projects. I use only the "Finish Build Trigger" in triggering options. Maybe I misunderstood the concept of TeamCity snapshot dependencies.

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't just add the VCS root of Project A to Project B? This way failures in either build will notify the users who made the code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to set it up through snapshot dependencies as Danere pointed out and it is working. Since the TC way is different from what you probably tried with Jenkins here is my setup:

1. I added another project to the chain named **C** that contains 2 VCS: projectA and projectB and a dummy build step.
2. Project **C** is configured to be triggered by any VCS change
3. Project **C** has a snapshot dependency on project **B**
4. Project **B** has a snapshot dependency on project **A**
5. Both project **A** and **B** do **not** have any triggers.

The project C could be probably eliminated but my configuration is more complex and the last step performs system tests and I didn't want it to monitor all VCSs of all the upstream projects.